# B1/b2 visa both travelling and working

Tags: visas, b1-b2-visas

I plan to go to the us for 3 months. I've been there before 3 times but stayed 3 weeks each time and only on B2. This time I plan to go for both visiting (my bf) and working. I will be working for my company's client in Philly but my vacation stay is in Wisconsin and the work would happen somewhere in the middle of my staying. Is this fine? Would they stamp both b1/b2 on my passport?

Comment: **Be Very Careful**. On a [B1 visitor visa](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/visit/visitor.html) you're not "working for" a company in the USA. You could be "conducting business" *for* your employer in your home country *with* the company in the USA. Getting this wrong puts you at significant risk of being turned around at the airport and sent straight back home with a black mark against your name. If you're going to be working in the USA, your employer should be getting you an appropriate visa (possibly with the help of a competent immigration attorney).

Comment: I willbe working for the company in my country, i will not get paid for the company in US. It's a delegation

Comment: Why does it matter what they stamp on your passport?